# Spring State Machine - Persist Libraries and Final State - Stops Listening

Tags: spring-statemachine

I was looking at spring state machine (spending a small amount of time evaluating, before being moved onto another project).

I wanted to use papyrus and UML modeling for an Order Flow.  This worked.  I had a REST interface working.  I expanded to look at the persistence demo and created a number of state machines using a cross-reference id.

I used thymeleaf to show the various orders, their states and send events.

This all seemed to work UNTIL any one of the state machines entered a "Final State" (The one that looks like a bullseye). At this point the AbstractPersistStateMachineHandler stopped triggering/listening and the onPersist no longer fired.

Is there an issue with using a "final state" and the persistence (https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/3.2.0/reference/#statemachine-recipes-persist) approach?

If i reworked it to just ensure this last state was a "normal" state (but with no exists) then it worked fine, but from a state model perspective probably doesnt accurately show that we have reached the end of the lifecyle.

Alot of what i did would have been based around: \spring-statemachine\spring-statemachine-samples\datapersist

Comment: maybe it works as designed, once machine gets to final state it is questionable why do you need a machine to keep listening to events. I havent used the persist recipe before, but I know that it is possible to manually update state machine records and related entities using custom implementation.